# How to get Enum when it's string representation and type are known at Runtime?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums

Suppose I have an Enum as:

```
com.mypackage.enums

public enum Days {

    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY
}
```

Now somewhere I know that I need to get enum MONDAY from a runtime string provided as "MONDAY". I also know that this enum lies in com.mypackage.enums.Days

How can I do this? With or without reflection?

EDIT: Both the string "MONDAY" and Class com.mypackage.enum.Days are determined at Runtime. Class is provided as object of Class and not as string.

Comment: Do you know that it's `Days` at *compile-time* or at *execution-time*? (If it's compile-time, just use `Days.valueOf(name)`)

Comment: It's known at the execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to @JonSkeet solution which does not involve raw types (only unchecked cast):

```
static <T extends Enum<T>> Enum<T> getValue(String className, String name)
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className);
    return Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String className = "Day";
    String name = "SATURDAY";
    // Note use of raw type       
    System.out.println("Parsed: " + getValue(className, name));
}
```

Of course if you already have the `Class` object, you can simply use

```
Enum.valueOf(classObj, name);
```

Comment: I declined the edit as I see no point of wrapping the `Enum.valueOf` call into another method if you already have the class object. Just use `Enum.valueOf` directly.

Comment: Yeah, that's right for the context of this post. I am doing a couple more operations in my original method.

Comment: Use of generic type `T` seems redundant. If you knew `T` you wouldn't need this method. The best you can do is return `Enum<?>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enum.valueOf(Class, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-):

```
import java.util.*;

enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String className = "Day";
        String name = "SATURDAY";
        // Note use of raw type       
        Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Enum value= Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
        System.out.println("Parsed: " + value);
    }
}
```

Now this uses the raw `Class` type, which is never terribly nice - but I'm not sure what the better alternative is here. Fundamentally generics is about situations where you know the types at compile-time, and you don't here.

You might want to add a bit of validation yourself, and then suppress the warning about raw types *just* for this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

perhapse valueOf ?

```
com.mypackage.enums.Days.valueOf("MONDAY");
```

For the runtime classes you can use static "valueOf" method

```
Enum.valueOf(yourRuntimeType, yourRuntimeString)
```

Comment: The class is also determined at runtime. Just updated the details.

Comment: well what about "Enum.valueOf(yourRuntimeType, yourRuntimeString)" ?

Comment: Right, used this finally.